# Pinch to zoom in with Cordova > 5.x.x

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I need to implement pinch to zoom on html page. I not able to do it with below code in MainActivity.java

- This is my first hybrid app
- Cordova(5.0.4) + JQM android application
- For Android target platform is API 23 and min sdk support version is API 14..
- code was working as expected before i updated cordova cli to 5.x.x.

Is there any updation with cordova > 5.x.x so that the above code is failing while build?

Thank you in advance.

```
import android.webkit.WebSettings; 
import android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity; 
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity  { 
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        // Set by in config.xml 
        loadUrl(launchUrl) 

        super.appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
        super.appView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM); 
        super.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is your target platform? What other things have you tried? Is this your first Hybrid App?

Comment: For Android target platform is API 23 and min sdk support version is API 14.. I have tried the above code only and it was working as expected before i updated cordova cli to 5.x.x.

Comment: I forgot to ask. Is this your first hybrid App?

Comment: Yes it is.. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Yes. I have an answer. Please review the changes I made to your post. See if you want to add anything.

Comment: Nope.. thanks for the changes

Answer (score 0):

@daxesh,
thanks for posting the question. When you have time read this FAQ:
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

One of the first things you should know - if you have anything to do on Cordova or Phonegap AND it is not available in the core set of functions, then you should look for a plugin to do what you need. The last thing you should every do is add native code (in this case Java, Objective-C if iOS). The only exception is if you are going to creat a plugin.

**For you task**, you want to make sure you have the appropriate setting, and look in Five (5) different places. To be clear, you will be doing the entire task with HTML5 and CSS3. This is because we are using the webview library.

1. setting in your viewport
2. settings in your CSS
3. sometimes there is a plugin to do what you need
4. sometimes you need to use a Javascript Library
5. settings with 3rd pary webview libraries

**On #1**, the most basic setting is:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Avoid using  `minimum-scale` and `maximum-scale`, or any other setting that constrict the resizing of the webview.

This mozilla article is a good reference, [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport) is a good resource too. You can also Google: [html5 viewport](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+viewport).

To be clear, there is no settings for "pinch to zoom", but if you tell the webview library not to allow a different "scale", then it will not resize - not matter what else you do. So make sure to use just what you *know* need and no more.

**On #2**, occasionally you will find a CSS3 setting that will help you get to where you need.

This video will help you get to where you want. At 12:25-16:15 he talks about "pinch to zoom", but you probably want to watch the whole video.
[Stephen Woods: "Creating Responsive HTML5 Touch Interfaces" (24 min.)](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2012/02/23/video-stephen-woods-html5-touch/)

You can also Google: [css webkit pinch](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+webkit+pinch)

**On #3**, 3rd Party plugins are at http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/. I find none at this time.

**On #4**, Occasionally it is easier to find a Javascript library that can handle the task. You will want to check these popular frameworks: [Ionic](https://www.google.com/search?q=ionic+pinch+zoom), [JQuery Mobile](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+mobile+pinch+zoom), [YUI](https://www.google.com/search?q=yui+mobile+pinch+zoom), [BootStrap](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+pinch+zoom)

**On #5**, when using Cordova/Phonegap every platform uses the default webview library that comes with the system. On iOS is is called UIWebView and WKWebview (there are two (2) libraries.).

However, sometimes you can use a third party library, like *[Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/)* or *[cordova-plugin-wkwebview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wkwebview) by eddyverbruggen*. When using these alternate libraries, you have to ask the author, if they have that support built in. Usually they do as they usually start with the [Webkit library](https://webkit.org/). To learn more about webkit issue, read Paul Irish's article: [Webkit for Developers](http://www.paulirish.com/2013/webkit-for-developers/). – Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like hammer.js (http://hammerjs.github.io/) for detecting the pinch gesture and then transform the content with JS/CSS. Don't rely on modifying Java inside Cordova/PhoneGap.

However if you **really** **really** need to do it this way (by modifying MainActivity.java) you may try this:

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadUrl(launchUrl);

        WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: this may come across a bit out of subject, but how can you actually edit the native android code (java), from a cordova application? I developed a project in Cordova in Visual studio and never figured how to exploit native capabilities for either Android or iOS